# Plot a column from a data frame as a function of another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a pandas data frame:

```
Name  A   B   C
 a1   2.0 1.1 2.5
 a2   2.2 3.4 8.7
 a3   4.3 4.4 2.3
```

I would like to plot C as a function of Name (Name is the index) the graph should look like:

```
y
|
|
------------->X
```

Where X should be the strings 'a1','a2','a3'..etc.. and the Y are the values of column C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the index and plot `'C'`

```
df.set_index('Name').C.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Is there a way to rotate the a1,a2, etc.. by 90 degrees? i'm using rotate=90 but it doesn't work.

Comment: `df.set_index('Name').C.plot(rot=90)`